# Openlayers Animated marker

Tags: openlayers-2, animation, markers

How to animated feature marker in openlayers like in google map example of [bouncing marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations). I'm new in openlayers so if you have a sample code much better.

Comment: I want to move a marker with animation from one location to another smoothly in openlayer. There is a sample: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html. But this has a polyline coordinates which consist of different characters. I want to move a marker with animation from one location (lat1,lon1) to new place (lat2,lon2) . I haven't find this for weeks. Pls help me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96320)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96320)

Answer (score 1):

You might use SVG symbols, like in this example:

http://www.netzwolf.info/kartografie/openlayers/svg.htm

or a simple moving marker:

http://www.netzwolf.info/kartografie/openlayers/bastelstube/animierter_marker

The source files should be self-explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right answer but this trick solve mine. I create a GIF (bouncing marker) then change the icon of existing marker (JPG) to GIF icon then adjust the size and offset. This my sample code.

```
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(w,h);                   // new height 
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);  // new offset
marker.setUrl("new_GIF_image_path");            //set new GIF icon path 
marker.icon.setSize(size);                      // set new size
marker.icon.offset=offset;                     // set new offset
markers.redraw();                      // redraw layer markers
```

If you have an easy or other answer let me know.